# getting stuck on a java excercise

Tags: java, swing, methods

heres the problem:

> “Numerology”
>   Create a program with a JFrame that allows a string input of a word into a text box and 
>       computes the sum of each letters’ value for the output. Be sure to include a “compute” 
>       and “exit” button. 
>       For example: sky = 55, because s = 19, k = 11, and y = 25, so 19 + 11 + 25 = 55.

```
    import java.awt.*; //Container, GridLayout, *, or etc...
    import javax.swing.*; //JFrame, JLabel, *, or etc...
    import java.awt.event.*;
    public class NumerologyEC extends JFrame
    {
        private static final int Width = 400;
        private static final int Height = 100;

        private JLabel wordJL;
        private JTextField wordTF;

        private JButton calculateJB, exitJB;

        private CalculateButtonHandler cbHandler;
        private ExitButtonHandler ebHandler;

       public  NumerologyEC()
       {
           setTitle ("Numerology Extra Credit");
           wordJL = new JLabel ("Enter a word: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);

           wordTF = new JTextField(10);

           calculateJB = new JButton ("Calculate");
           cbHandler = new CalculateButtonHandler();
           calculateJB.addActionListener (cbHandler);

           exitJB = new JButton ("Exit");
           ebHandler = new ExitButtonHandler();
           exitJB.addActionListener (ebHandler);

           Container pane = getContentPane();
           pane.setLayout (new GridLayout (2, 2));

           pane.add(wordJL);
           pane.add(wordTF);
           pane.add(calculateJB);
           pane.add(exitJB);

           setSize(Width, Height);
           setVisible (true);
           setDefaultCloseOperation (EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        }

          private class CalculateButtonHandler  implements ActionListener
        {
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
            {
                String word;



            }
        }

        private class ExitButtonHandler implements ActionListener
        {
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
            {
              System.exit (0);  
            }
        }

       public static void main (String[] args)
       {
        NumerologyEC rectObject = new NumerologyEC();
        }


    }
```

What method should i use to solve the problem? i already set up my jframe now i just need a way to solve this problem. im just a beginner so im still trying to figure stuff out when it comes to programming. any tips is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need a method sumCharValues that takes a string, iterates over the characters, adding their int value (with A = 1, B = 2) and returns the sum. E.g.

```
private int sumCharValues (String input) {
  String str = input.toLowerCase(); // so 'A' and 'a' are equivalent
  int result = 0;
  for (int i = 0, n = str.length(); i < n; i++) {
    char c = str.charAt(i);
    result += (c - 'a' + 1);
  }
  return result;
}
```

You will have to call this method from the handler of the "compute" handler and have a JLabel to display the resulting value.

Comment: thank you. ur not like the other people here who makes beginners feel stupid. this helps a lot.

Comment: Glad to help. Don't forget to mark my answer as the right one :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to read about event listeners. I will not give you direct answers but hints. Look at Javadocs and see what methods are available on ActionEvent. Google can be a handy tool.